# Google Search Prediction/ Autofill option is Not Getting Removed by Shift+Del

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, auto-form-fill

I have an Obsolete link to a File-sharing [Mega](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn6ht.png) service.
When clicked it goes to a Error Page. But shows up first in all search predictions.

I Have tried clearing all search history and of course removing the entry by `Shift`+`Del`.

More than Inconvenient, its an eyesore.

Can anyone suggest to me how to go about removing this entry.

Comment: Check if that URL is included in your bookmarks. If so, remove it from your bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you.That was the problem. It is now solved.